# Laravel: How to I pass a Blade template to the client side via JSON?

Tags: json, client-side, mustache, laravel

I wish to pass a JSON object that includes some HTML to my client-side application. I'm using Laravel 3.2.12 and I'm new to it.I know the problem is in my `View::make` directive. Which is the correct directive then?

In My_Controller:

```
public function get_all()
{
    return Response::json(array(
        array('name' => 'OR', 'category' => 'Logical', 'form_controls' => View::make('modules.or'))
    ));
}
```

In views/modules/or.blade.php:

```
<span>test</span>
```

In views.js:

```
$('#element').html(Mustache.to_html(ModuleTemplate, {some: 'stuff'}, { custom: this.model.get("form_controls") }));
```

In view.mustache:

```
...
{{>custom}}
...
```

The HTML inside the JSON should be parsed by mustache.js as a partial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is View::render();

http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Laravel.View.html#311

As far as I know, View::make returns a full response object which is not what you want.

Comment: Thank you, thank you. The documentation is not clear enough about this. Of course, it's always easy to blame the documentation.

Comment: There isn't really any documentation for this helper. Found this helper by diving into the source code. It really should be documented though.